# Domain and range of $\frac{3x+2}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that  $$\frac{3x+2}{x}$$

How to find its domain and range?

I know $x\neq0$, so domain will be $x<0$ or $x>0$. But the answer given x is also $\neq$-1. Why?

Comment: Note that $(3\cdot 1 + 2 )/ 1 = 5$ and $(3 \cdot (-1)+2)/(-1)=1$, so $1$ is both in the domain and in the range of the function. This means that somebody gave you an incorrect answer.

Comment: Wolfram alpha states its domain $x\neq-1$ also. @Crostul

Comment: Either he is telling you a wrong answer or he means that it is a one-to-one function and there must have been a misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1):

The domain of this function is $\mathbb{R}-\left\{0\right\}$

Because $\dfrac{3*0+2}{0} = \dfrac{2}{0} = undefined$

---

The range of this function is $\mathbb{R}-\left\{3\right\}$

Because

Let $\dfrac{3x+2}{x}=y$

or, $x=\dfrac{2}{y-3}$

Hence $y\neq 3$

---

Further info :

[image: 3x+2 / x]

[General Info] >>> http://goo.gl/3Hkygb

[Domain and Range] >>> http://goo.gl/uDCeC4

---

$x \neq 1$ is FALSE...

Comment: But Wolfram Alpha states its domain $x\neq-1$. Why?

Comment: @Mathxx No...check it in http://goo.gl/uDCeC4

Answer (score 0):

The domain in interval notation is $ (-\infty,0) \bigcup (0,\infty)$.

You can find the range of a rational function by finding any horizontal asymptotes and/or holes (removeable discontinuities). Here's a good [link](http://www.math-magic.com/algebra/asymptote.htm).

There is a horizontal asymtote at $ y = 3 $.

So the range is: $ (-\infty,3) \bigcup (3,\infty)$.

Comment: Hello: Guidelines: "While voting down a post signals... the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information. Which one, if any???